# How do I check if a specific item in pandas series is NaT

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series of random dates which have some NaT values in it (for example: index 112875)

```
DataFrame['series']
0        2006-06-06
1        2006-09-06
2        2006-12-22
3        2007-03-09
4        2007-06-05
            ...    
112871   2019-10-29
112872   2020-02-27
112873   2020-04-28
112874   2020-07-28
112875          NaT
Name: series, Length: 112876, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

what I'm trying to figure out is when approaching a specific NaT value, to what should I compare it in order to get True?

```
IN  [5] DataFrame['series'][112875] == None
OUT [5] False
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `DataFrame["series"].isna()`?

Comment: I'm familiar with .isna() but it just gives me a series of boolean values and I asked for a boolean answer for a specific cell.  thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `DataFrame['series'].str.contains('NaT')`

This gives True if row contains ***NaT***

Comment: interesting solution. could be useful in many different cases. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DataFrame['series'][112875] is pd.NaT

>>> True
```